# Twitter Login Functionality In Swift

Tags: ios, swift, twitterkit

I am integrating twitter login in my app but i am getting error using twitterkit

**EX:**  **Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings**

and for that i refer this link can anyone please tell me that this method for login in proper

**Referral URL**:: https://www.brewit9.com/2017/10/twitter-login-integration-in-ios-using.html

and please give me solution for that error

Comment: Try to search first before post otherwise your question will be close soon.

Answer (score 1):

change setting in your twitter developer account for callback url

```
twitterkit-<Your Api Key>://
```

E.g :

```
twitterkit-alsjdln23r4n23lk4n234://
```

Comment: Yes its working now Thanks